# column alias as NUMBER in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I am using a number as alias  in select query in PostgreSQL

```
Select json->>'1' as 1 from myTable
```

It shows an error

> "error in query near 1".

It works fine if we dont use number (eg. json->>'1' as data )

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Double quotes for identifiers:

```
Select json->>'1' as "1" 
from myTable
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Answer (score 0):

Use double quotes:

```
Select json->>'1' as "1" from myTable
```

Comment: You need to use quotes, but *double* quotes for identifiers.